# maven: plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration error

Tags: maven

I recently was asked to check out a project folder from svn server to my local box. Everything (checked out java source files and properties file) seems fine except pom.xml file it has red error icon next to it with following message"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configurations: org.apache.maven.plugin". When I reviewed the contents of it,

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</validate>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
```

The execution tag has red underline. It says 3 quick fixes available:
1) permanently makr goal run in pom.xml as ignored in eclipse build
2) make goal run as ignored in eclipse build in eclipse preferences 
3) discover new m2e connectors

I am not sure how to fix that problem. I'd appreciate advice on this.

I have eclipse kepler as IDE to open/compile java source file and subversive plugin to sync with svn server. I have maven_local_repo_artifactory folder set up in C: drive and maven_settings_artifactory.xml file. I believe that my all dependencies are under artifactory folder.

[update]

I see also C:\maven_local_repo directory. Not sure why it is there though. C:\maven_local_repo_artifcatory contains almost exact number of dependencies. And settings.xml file is missing....

If I run clean-compile via maven I get following error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.675s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 12 08:11:40 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project xyz-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Does any maven project work? And what are the contents of {M2_HOME}\setting.xml (or, if that's not there - {M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml ) ?

Comment: {M2_HOME} is missing...

Comment: run maven with -X and check the debug logs to see where is the setting.xml file you use. Also, check if java home is set correctly.

Comment: forgive me asking this. how do i run "maven -x" within eclipse? maven_home variable is missing also from environment variables.

Comment: Oh, right, eclipse... I never use that plugin for building, don't trust it to do what I ask it to do. Anyway, in eclipse that info should be available in preferences -> Maven -> User Settings

Comment: I ran "run as > Maven test" to see if I could run maven command. It generated same output as I mentioned. Also I realized that .m2 folder I deleted a while ago for whatever the reason. I restored it back, but i don't see settings.xml file.

Comment: forgive me my late reply. user settings point to c:\workspace\maven_local_repo_artifactory\maven_settings_artifactory.xml